# Falling side detection in XNA

Tags: c#, xna-4.0, farseer

I want to make a small app in XNA & Farseer. Basically, I have a sprite (a crate). Every side of the crate has a different color: RED, GREEN, BLUE, YELLOW. I throw the crate. I want to detect on which side the crate falls.  I want the app to tell me that the crate has fallen on YELLOW side or on RED side and so on.

Thank you.

Comment: that means it is a rectangle...right?

Comment: @HackerMan Yes (Rectangle or square)

Comment: Show us the code for how you throw the square.